# regular expression /\<div id=\"current_city\" class=\"current_city\"\>(.*?)\<\/div\>/

Tags: regex, html-parsing

regular expression

> `/\<div id=\"current_city\" class=\"current_city\"\>(.*?)\<\/div\>/`

Someone can fixe this mess ?

> $cookie_file_path = "fb.txt";
>
> $fbplink1="https://www.facebook.com/profile/about";
>
> $fbplinkfinal = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $fbplink1);
>
> ```
> $ch = curl_init();
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fbplinkfinal);
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $fbplinkfinal);
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
> ```
>
> curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US;rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
>
> ```
> $result = curl_exec($ch);
>
> curl_close($ch); $Getcurrentcity=preg_match_all("\<div id='current_city' class\=(.*?)\>(.*?)\<\/div\>",$result,$currentcity);
>
> <textarea value="<?echo $currentcity[0][0];?>" ></textarea>
> ```

Comment: Need some cheers from the community? Don't underestimate yourself, I'm sure you'll do just fine !

Comment: i spent 4 hours but didnt work !!!

Comment: what language and what input data does it have?

Comment: @user3546707: Do you have a question?

Comment: im try to get current city from facebook but doesnt work

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php or [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: i would use specific div id class , it wont work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$elem = $dom->getElementById("current_city");
$textData = $elem->textContent;
preg_match("/(?<=Edit).+?(?=,)/", $textData, $city);
echo $city[0];
?>
```

Here's a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/xQ0uO9) of the regex that I've used.

Comment: You need to store the entire HTML Document contents as a DOMDocument type in the variable $dom before executing the above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cookie_file_path = "fb.txt";
$fbplink1="https://www.facebook.com/profile/about";
$fbplinkfinal = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $fbplink1);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fbplinkfinal);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $fbplinkfinal);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);   
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US;rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


preg_match_all('%<div id="current_city" class="current_city">(.*?)</div>%', $buffer, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[1][0];

echo $result;
```